# Can you end Beast Form early?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there any way to end beast form early? I find myself using it to clear out a particularly hard portion of a dungeon at times, but then I have to sit around for 2-5 minutes so I can be my human character again (I have to feed to keep my health up, so I'm a werewolf longer than the 2.5 minutes).

Is there anyway to end it early?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One hour of waiting in Skyrim is approximately equal to 180 seconds (tested using shout cooldown times - a 180 second cooldown was ready after waiting 1 hour, while a 300 second cooldown required me to wait for 2 hours). As your time as a werewolf is equal to 150 seconds + 30 seconds per "feed", if you've fed on a large number of bodies in werewolf form, you may need to wait several hours.

I have also noticed that the check to see if it's time to turn back to normal appears to be run only every few seconds, so you may need to stand around for a moment after waiting in order for the transformation to occur.

Comment: By default, one hour of game time is _exactly_ equal to 180 seconds (3 minutes) of real-world time - Skyrim's default timescale is 20, meaning that game time passes at 20 times the rate of real-world time. (Note that you can change the timescale in the console; personally, I prefer a timescale of 5.)

Answer (score 6):

I found just using the wait function for a quick hour to be the best, so once you clear a room just tap the select button or what not and once your in game hour has gone by you'll be your naked self pretty quick.

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing on the PC, you can install the **[Werewolf Revert Form](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/24521)** mod by RolandSir, which will allow you to press a key to revert from werewolf form without needing to wait.

Mod description:

> Have you ever wanted to revert from werewolf form, but pressing the "T" button and waiting was too long and annoying?
>
> Revert to human form by pressing "R" button (or, if you have reassigned the buttons, the one that sheathes your weapon), then press "Z" to activate revert function and continue your travels!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feed, just Wait for 1–2 hours and you will transform back.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just sleep. Like if It's ps3 you press select and you set it to maybe 2 hours.

Answer (score -1):

I was in werewolf form, and needed to transform back to burn the barrier to get into dragons reach. i was farming werewolf perks, to level the werewolf form quickly.  I had fed on a ton of soldiers, friend and foe. 
 waiting a couple hours wasn't working, but waiting about 36 hours was enough time to revert form.
 when you feed, you stack more time onto your remaining wolf time, the more you eat the longer it takes to revert form. if waiting hasn't worked, try waiting 24 hours at a time until you turn back.